# fastify route handler not initiating after onRequest hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, webhooks, fastify

i'm writing a fastify app that is supposed to listen for post requests and capture the raw body of the request for authentication purposes. Since i've searched far and wide for it it seems that fastify has no built in support for this and any solutions i did find plain did not work so i decided to use the onRequest hook which worked flawlessly for capturing the data but somehow had the excruciating side effect of causing the route handler for the associated path to not work. i am positive my testing is correct since if i remove the hook the route handler starts functioning again and even if i add it back in with no logic it works but the moment i add the data capturing logic it stops.

the output of the code was the log that the hook is running the packets in hexadecimal and then the complete raw json and nothing else where the route handler should have logged that its running

```
fastify.addHook('onRequest', (request, reply, done) => {
console.log('onRequest hook is running');
const rawDataChunks = [];

request.raw.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk);
    rawDataChunks.push(chunk);
});

request.raw.on('end', () => {
    console.log('RAW DATA:', Buffer.concat(rawDataChunks).toString());
    request.rawData = Buffer.concat(rawDataChunks).toString();
    done();
    });
});
//route does not execute
fastify.post('/', (request, reply) => {
console.log('Route handler is running');
});
```

Comment: I would suggest my plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-raw-body (built to work with stripe)

Comment: ideally id like to know why what i am doing isnt working before trying to figure out another tool

Comment: Wrong approch for the community, share your finding - you are consuming the raw body, so fastify can't consume it anymore during the parsing and it gets stuck. I'm travelling so I can't check and open an issue on fastify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastify has a default [content type parser](https://fastify.dev/docs/v2.15.x/Documentation/ContentTypeParser) which handles the request body stream and parse it.

Since your `onRequest` hook consumes the request body stream, the parser fails and gets stuck.

Just for testing, you can disable any content parser and your code will work:

```js
fastify.removeAllContentTypeParsers();
```

(Note that removing any content type parsing might not be the best solution, but it can help you understand the request flow)